# Get the total cost based on cost/pieces and quantity

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image]

I want a formula to calculate the total cost of each row. Here's an example:

Lets say I want 7 M2x25 bolts. They are being sold for $3.24 for 50 pieces. How much would 7 bolts cost?

I'm new to Excel, but perhaps it could parse the `Part cost` cells as such: `between $ and / is variable A. Between / and p is variable B.` `A / B * Quantity = Total cost`

Comment: The best would be to put the two numbers in their own cells, then you could just do the math.

Comment: yeah, but I want them in the same cell so it's easier for me to read, plus I tend to make things more difficult for myself

Comment: You can format the cells so it appears to be in one cells, but acts like two.  Other than that, what have you tried to parse the data?  This really is not a site to do the work for you

Comment: As @ScottCraner states, you have a mix of **numbers** and **letters** in the column *Part cost*. Excel has limited "intelligence" and doesn't "know" what to do with that mix. You either have to make things simpler (separate the two items, cost and quantity, and get rid of 'pcs'), or make a parser to figure out what that column means in a way Excel can calculate an answer.

Comment: You really should put the `50pcs` in one or two new columns maybe: `lot size` and `lot unit`. Then you wouldn't need a fancy formula that might break because of bad formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use new version of Excel (365) you can try formula:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(Part_cost,"/")/SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(Part_cost,"/"),"pcs","")*Quantity
```

Define names `Part_cost` and `Quantity` or replace them by addresses.

Comment: Thanks. I replaced Part_cost and Quantity with the addresses and added $ to the front, then pasted it to every row.